# Value from a JSON file to change the background of element

Tags: reactjs, json

I have a JSON file that I am calling with Axios to fetch data, in the data is a value. When this value is present, I want to change the background colour. Sounds simple enough but I am struggling with the logic of this.

Here is my code:

https://gcpzn.csb.app/

Here is some of my thinking on how to solve this:

In the test.json data above we get the data of type: "dev"
there will be dev, stage, live
from this JSON data, I need to be able to change the background colour based on these values
I was thinking of using a switch statement but this is where I am stuck at.

```
If the item.type is dev then I want the background to change to yellow
If the item.type is stage then I want the background to change to red
If the item.type is live then I want the background to change to green
```

How would you go about solving this issue as I am stuck and need a little help, please?

Thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget that calling an API is an asynchronous process.
Here is your [modified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sinoussi-udv9f?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for that, but it is the switch statement that isn't working by the looks of things! Cheers!

Comment: It is working correctly for testing it. Please hardcode the `data` to `'STAGE'`.

Comment: @daveCodesCode
I have just refactored your code.

Comment: Solved it here: https://983ky.csb.app/

Thanks for your help :)